# why AspCompat = true is making my asp web application slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing one asp.net application.
In that on one page I have one TextBox and one button.
When I click Button one popup should come and it will ask me to save the text of TextBox in a file on my desired path.

Its giving me error 
"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process"

```
   protected void ButtonIDSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
            //saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()))
                {
                    sw.Write(TextBoxIDPVMContent.Text);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // ex;
        }
    }
```

So to removie this error, I have made change into my aspx file 
AspCompat="true" in

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ABC.cs" Inherits="XYZ" ValidateRequest = "false" %>
```

Its making my application hanged.
So how can I get rid of this issue ??
Or is there any alternative way to achieve this functionality??
Why Its making my application very slow??

On the other hand, I have created one small asp web application and doing same work, like I have one page with one textbox and one button and I want to save data of textbox into a file. In this application its working pretty fine.

I am stuck on this issue since morning, I know there will some small trick behind this problem.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to directly translate a Windows Forms app into a Web Form app. This can't be done, without horrible results.

Comment: There is no "trick" to programming. The only trick is to understand what you're doing. You are trying to display a Windows Forms control (SaveFileDialog) in a website project. This will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `SaveFileDialog` in a web environment. That is for Windows Forms. Mixing Windows Forms components and ASP.NET can have *unusual* side effects and it won't work as you intend it to.

That is why I assume you commented out the call to `ShowDialog`.

Comment: plus, that is a new question, which is not related to this one.

Comment: Yes on Client compute, I have commented ShowDialog because this line is giving me error